# Audit.EntityFramework.Core how to store changes to multiple tables without creating audit objects

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, audit.net

iam using Audit.EntityFramework.Core library to setup audit log in my new application.

Following guide i setup my dbContext (see below code) but from what i can understand it seems that i have to create in my domain a specific object for every real object i want to log but honestly they have no sense in a DDD perspective.Moreover i see no example of how these objects should be

Is there a way to tell library simply the name of the tables where to store logs, like for example what i did with Envers (library for audit log NHibernate)?

```
public class DatabaseContext : AuditDbContext, IDatabaseContext
{
    private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;

    #region Ctor
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
     : base(options)
    {
        _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
        //this.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
        this.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        Audit.EntityFramework.Configuration.Setup()
            .ForContext<DatabaseContext>(config => config
                .IncludeEntityObjects()
                .AuditEventType("{context}:{database}"))
            .UseOptOut()
                .IgnoreAny(t => t.Name.EndsWith("History"));


        Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
        .UseEntityFramework(x => x
        .UseDbContext<DatabaseContext>()
        .AuditTypeNameMapper(typeName => "Audit_" + typeName)
        .AuditEntityAction((ev, ent, auditEntity) =>
        {
            // auditEntity is object
            ((dynamic)auditEntity).AuditDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }));
    }
    #endregion
    #region DbSet
    public DbSet<ParametroConfigurazione> ParametriConfigurazione { get; set; }
    #endregion
    #region Methods
    public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync() => base.SaveChangesAsync();
    #endregion

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(ParametroConfigurazioneConfiguration).Assembly);


        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(_loggerFactory)
            .AddInterceptors(new AuditCommandInterceptor()
            {
                ExcludeNonQueryEvents = true,
                AuditEventType = "DatabaseContext",
                IncludeReaderResults = true
            })
            ;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you seen the documentation on how to [_Map multiple entity types to the same audit type_](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/README.md#map-multiple-entity-types-to-the-same-audit-type-with-independent-actions)?

Comment: yes, but i need different table not a single one